# rsync to backup one file generated in dynamic folders

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I'm trying to backup just one file that is generated by other application in dynamic named folders. 
for example:

```
parent_folder/ 
   back_01 -> file_blabla.zip (timestam 2013.05.12)
   back_02 -> file_blabla01.zip (timestam 2013.05.14)
   back_03 -> file_blabla02.zip (timestam 2013.05.22)
```

and I need to get the latest generated zip, just that one it doesnt matter the name of the file as long as is the latest, is a zip and is inside "parent_folder" get that one.

as well when I do the rsync the folder structure + file name is generated and I want to omit that I want to backup that file in a folder and with a name so I know where is the latest and it will be always named the same.

now im doing this with a perl that get the latest generated folder with

```
"ls -tAF | grep '/$' | head -1"
```

and perform the rsync but it does brings the last zip but with the folder structure that I dont want because it doesnt override my latest zip file.

```
rsync -rvtW --prune-empty-dirs --delay-updates --no-implied-dirs --modify-window=1 --include='*.zip' --exclude='*.*' --progress /source/ /myBackup/
```

as well it would be great if I could do the rsync without needing to use perl or any other script.

thanks

Comment: try the last bit.. the one liner example is probably the tidiest. the example above it is the same thing but done the long winded more expanded way. Peace

Answer (score 1):

The file names will differ each time ?

This would be hard for any type of syncing to work.

What you could do is :

- create a new folder outside of where it is found, then :
- Before you start remove the last sym linked file in that folder
- When the file is found i.e. ls -tAF | grep '/$' | head -1 ....
  symlink it this folder
- then rsync,ssh,unison file across to new node.
- If the symlink name is file-latest.zip then it will always be this
  one file sent across.

But why do all that when you can just scp and you can take a look at here:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/definedscp
for a more long winded approach, and not for this situation but it uses the real file date/time stamp then converts to seconds... It might be useful if you wish to do the stat in a different way

Using stat to work out file, work out latest file then simply scp it across, here is something to get you started:

One liner:

```
scp  $(find /path/to/parent_folder -name \*.zip  -exec stat -t {} \;|awk '{print $1" "$13}'|sort -k2nr|head -n1|awk '{print $1}') remote_server:/path/to/name.zip
```

More long winded way, maybe of use to understand what above is doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOUND_ARRAY=()
cd parent_folder;
for file in $(find . -name \*.zip); do
  ptime=$(stat -t $file|awk '{print $13}');   
  FOUND_ARRAY+=($file" "$ptime)
done


IFS=$'\n'
FOUND_FILE=$(echo "${FOUND_ARRAY[*]}" | sort -k2nr | head -n1|awk '{print $1}');
scp $FOUND_FILE remote_host:/backup/new_name.zip
```