# shell script for comparing files between two servers

Tags: shell

Hey I'm looking for Shell script to transfer compressed archives from server a to server b. Only the compressed archives which have not been transferred should be transfer from server a to server b.

Please don't say scp or rsync because it will copy all the files from server a to server b.
I want the script which compare the existence of the file in the server b. If the file does not exist in server b then it has to transer that file from server a to server b.

Comment: Do you want to run this script on server a or server b?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with rsync?

Comment: Maybe you should read a little about rsync.  I'm no expert, but a quick glance at [`man rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) suggests that `rsync -e` will skip files that already exist on the receiving machine... Could you please explain why that won't work for you?

Comment: A provacative quote from the [`rsync man page`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync): "_Rsync is a fast and extraordinarily versatile file copying tool... It offers a large number of options that control every aspect of its behavior and permit very flexible specification of the set of files to be copied._"

Answer (score 1):

As Oli points out - this is exactly what rsync does.... But if you want to go the manual way  thentake at my answer here  [rsync to backup one file generated in dynamic folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719499/rsync-to-backup-one-file-generated-in-dynamic-folders/)

What you could also do for the comparison is ssh first to host a by running command and storing its output locally

```
ssh localhost "find /var/tmp/ -name \* -exec du -sm {} \;" > /tmp/out.txt

head /tmp/out.txt 
531 /var/tmp/
0   /var/tmp/aaa
1   /var/tmp/debian
```

You now have a file locally with remote filenames,sizes feel free to expand as required